# Two masses on frictionless table with one string connecting both masses on ground and the other string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

From Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics page 342:

> A solid cylinder of mass $m$ and radius $r$ lies flat on frictionless
>   horizontal table, with a massless string running halfway around it, as
>   shown in Fig. 8.50. A mass also of mass $m$ is attached to one end of
>   the string, and you pull on the other end with a force $T$. The
>   circumference of the cylinder is sufficiently rough so that the string
>   does not slip with respect to it. What is the acceleration of the mass
>   $m$ attached to the end of the string?

[image]

I am really confused of this question. It seems that center of mass of the system of both mass will be $T/(2m)$. And maybe one may use no-slip condition on the above string, but in general as this is frictionless table, one may not apply no-slip condition on the cylinder. But I am not sure how to proceed.

Edit:

So this is what I got:

$$rT-rF = I\alpha = mr^2\alpha/2$$
$$T-F = mr\alpha/2$$

$\alpha$ is angular acceleration.

$$a_{cm-of-cylinder} = (T+F)/m$$
and 
$$F = -ma_{y}$$

Let us call the upper string $x$ lower string $y$, and the positive direction points to right.

$$a_x = r\alpha = -a_y = 2(T-F)/m = F/m$$

Solving the equation, we get:

$$F = 2T/3$$, and $$a_y = -2T/(3m)$$.

But answer says that $$a_y = -T/(4m)$$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In what direction is gravity? (or equivalently, where is the table)?

Comment: @Eoin: "A solid cylinder [...] *lies flat* on frictionless table" Note this point.

Comment: @user29157: "*It seems that center of mass of the system of both mass will be $T/(2m)$*." It seems that there is something wrong here.

Comment: @Godparticle, but touching the table tangentially or on a flat face? Both work for the wording.

Comment: @Eoin: "*lies **flat** on the frictionless table*"- This might help you.

Comment: @user29157: If you have the final answer, add it in the question.

Comment: @Godparticle, no it doesn't actually. If I have a pencil, and I lie it "flat" on a table, it touches the table tangentially.

Answer (score 0):

The center of mass moves as though the string is connected there, but the disk is going to start rotating - this affects the motion.

You need to write down a couple of equations: one that describes the motion of the center of mass, and another the describes the change in distance between the disk and the mass at the end of the string. For this you must note that the tension on the string between the disk and the mass is **less than** the tension T - because the disk starts rotating and you need a torque on the disk to make that happen.

That's how you approach this. Is it enough to get you going?

Comment: Can you have a look over my edit? I added how I tried to solve the problem, but how it did not work out. Thanks.

Comment: You need to draw a diagram and look closely at the displacement of x and y - they are not the same. Your statement $a_x=-a_y$ is where you go wrong (the center of mass is accelerating due to the net force T on the system).